# How to create menu responsive on click or on hover depend on device?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I was creating a button with a and what I wanted is when I'm on a mobile device, I can click on the button and the menu appears. As we know, we can't hover on mobile devices But on a tab and higher devices, the menu should display on hover, not on click. [codepen](https://codepen.io/kumarmasterpraveen/pen/jOMoNZo)
If I use `onclick` for mobile devices, then the menu stays on medium and above devices and If I remove onclick to work properly on medium and above devices then on mobile we can't click, as the only option left to open the menu is hover which we can't do in mobile devices. How to solve this problem.
The only goal is to make a responsive design.

```js
const btn = document.querySelector('.btn');
const list = document.querySelector('.list');

btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  list.style.display = 'block';
})
```

```css
.btn{
  margin: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: teal;
  color: white;
  font-size: 2rem;
  border-radius: 8px;
}

.list{
  display: none;
}

.btn:hover + .list{
    display: block;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .btn{
    width: 50%;
  }
}
```

```html
<a class="btn"> Names </a>

<ul class="list">
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
  <li>Item 4</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go read about media queries in JavaScript and you can put a different onClick even based on the size of the window: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_media_queries.asp

Comment: I didn't know that we can also add event listeners based on the size of the window.

Comment: It worked, but I wanna know if we can test it on the desktop. As we always have to refresh for work js media queries

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```js
const btn = document.querySelector('.btn');
const list = document.querySelector('.list');
const header = document.querySelector('header')
let clicked = false

btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    clicked = !clicked;
    list.classList.toggle('active');
})

btn.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
    if (!clicked) {
        list.classList.add('active');
    }
})

btn.addEventListener('mouseout', () => {
    if (!clicked) {
        setTimeout(400);
        list.classList.remove('active');
    }
})

list.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
    if (!clicked) {
        list.classList.add('active');
    }
})

list.addEventListener('mouseout', () => {
    if (!clicked) {
        list.classList.remove('active');
    }
})
```

```css
.btn {
        margin: 0;
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        padding: 1rem;
        background-color: teal;
        color: white;
        font-size: 2rem;
        border-radius: 8px;
    }

    .list {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 16px 0;
        padding-left: 40px;
        display: none;
    }

    .list.active {
        display: block;
    }

    @media (min-width: 768px) {
        .btn {
            width: 50%;
        }
    }
```

```html
<header>
    <a class="btn">Names</a>

    <ul class="list">
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
        <li>Item 3</li>
        <li>Item 4</li>
    </ul>
</header>
<p> Some text to increase height of window and let you pass mouse out of the list: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
```

I replace the margin by padding to increase trigger zone of the list

```
margin: 0;
padding: 16px 0;
padding-left: 40px;
```

I add event for the list to avoid that it toggle active even if the mouse is over the list

```
list.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
    if (!clicked) {
        list.classList.add('active');
    }
})

list.addEventListener('mouseout', () => {
    if (!clicked) {
        list.classList.remove('active');
    }
})
```

I add `clicked` var to keep list `display: block` if you click on the button.
I add timeout to let time to transition between `btn` and `list` mouse over

Answer (score 0):

You have to add 'touch' event, by this way it gonna work with touchscreens only

```js
btn.addEventListener('touchstart', () => {
  list.style.display = 'block';
})
```